# Sorted values not correctly sorted

Tags: ruby, sorting, hashmap

I am stumped by the sorting algorithm that is employed by the sorting method for a hash object.  I have an hash with the following key values which are all floats.

```
0
0.0113867473179591
103.77896959717717
2.039453159239391
99.99575298164214
```

These are the values I got when I use map_values.values.sort().  I don't understand why 103.778.... comes before 2.0394...

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Are your values strings? This kind of sorting makes sense when dealing with strings. If you want to sort by the float values you should convert the strings to floats.

```
map_values.values.map(&:to_f).sort
```